# H265 does not show up as an option in Linphone App iOS

Tags: ios, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am trying to enable the H265 codec in the Linphone App for iOS but I don't know how to.

I have successfully built both the app and its sdk.

When one goes to Settings -> Video, under CODECS in the app, there are only the VP8 and H264 codecs available.

I thought that compiling the SDK with all video support and all 3rd party components should be enough.

This is how I have compiled the SDK:

Prepare:

```
cmake .. -G Ninja -DLINPHONESDK_PLATFORM=IOS -DENABLE_VIDEO=YES -DENABLE_ZRTP=YES -DENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES=YES
```

Build:

```
cmake --build .
```

Everything built successfully and I have referenced the built SDK in my Linphone project.

The SDK version is 4.2:

*"Installing linphone-sdk 4.4.0-alpha.167+f8422b1 (was 4.2)"*

The app version is 4.1.0 and in its read me file one can see:

*"Video H.265 codec support, based on iOS VideoToolbox framework."*

After rebuilding everything and running it, I am still unable to see H265 show up under CODECS.

Does anybody know what else I have to do to enable H265 ?

Also, I have downloaded the Linphone app from the App Store and noticed that it too does not include the H265 video codec.

My device is an iPhone 6S running iOS 12.4.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is due to the hardware of the phone; iPhone 6S does not support encoding H265... it does seem to work on an iPhone X.